# Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cassandra

I am developing a restful API using spring and Cassandra. The maven build has no error but while deploying the war in tomcat following error is shown.

P.S. :  I am new to Spring and Cassandra and also i am currently a intern and this is my intern project. Please Help

**Error:**

```
07-Aug-2017 11:39:19.812 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [ai.sys.webutils.JPAConfig]; nested exception is java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 9; Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:182)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 9; Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.load(PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.java:80)
    at java.util.Properties$XmlSupport.load(Properties.java:1201)
    at java.util.Properties.loadFromXML(Properties.java:881)
    at org.springframework.util.DefaultPropertiesPersister.loadFromXml(DefaultPropertiesPersister.java:78)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:91)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:72)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:58)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:361)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:255)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:168)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 9; Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1599)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1877)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:742)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1359)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1289)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.getLoadingDoc(PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.java:106)
    at sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.load(PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.java:78)
    ... 34 more

07-Aug-2017 11:39:20.046 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

**cxf_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" 
    xmlns:cassandra="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/cassandra"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cql 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cql/spring-cql.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/cassandra 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/cassandra/spring-cassandra.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        ">




    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/runtime/plutom-nextgen-context-api.properties" />
    <cassandra:cluster contact-points="${cassandra.contactpoints}" port="${cassandra.port}"/>
    <cassandra:session keyspace-name="${cassandra.keyspace}"></cassandra:session>
    <cassandra:mapping></cassandra:mapping>
    <cassandra:converter/>
    <cassandra:template id ="cassandraTemplate"/>
    <cassandra:repositories base-package="ai.sys.core.dao"></cassandra:repositories>


    <jaxrs:server id="sysServer" address="/api">
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="accessDeniedExceptionMapperProvider" />
            <ref bean="dataCreateExceptionMapperProvider" />
            <ref bean="dataNotFoundExceptionMapperProvider" />
            <ref bean="dataUpdateExceptionMapperProvider" />
            <ref bean="dataDeleteExceptionMapperProvider" />
            <ref bean="JSONProvider" />
            <ref bean="SearchContextProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="employeeServiceImpl" />

        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="SearchContextProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.SearchContextProvider" />

    <bean id="JSONProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
        <property name="readXsiType" value="false" />
        <property name="writeXsiType" value="false" />
        <property name="serializeAsArray" value="true" />
        <!-- <property name="arrayKeys" ref="jsonKeys" /> -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="byteMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
    <bean id="stringMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
    <bean id="formMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
    <bean id="sourceMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter" />
    <bean id="jaxb2MessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter" />


    <bean id="ehCacheManager"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jaxb2MessageConverter" />
                <ref bean="byteMessageConverter" />
                <ref bean="stringMessageConverter" />
                <ref bean="formMessageConverter" />
                <ref bean="sourceMessageConverter" />
                <ref bean="jaxb2MessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/classes/locale/messages" />
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean id="marshallingConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter"> 
        <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" /> <property name="supportedMediaTypes" 
        value="application/xml" /> </bean> -->

    <!-- <bean id="propertyLoader" parent="dataSource" class="ai.sys.webservice.util" 
        scope="prototype"> <property name="mysqlproperties" value="classpath:sqlproperties"/> 

        <property name="cassandraproperties" value="classpath:cassandraproperties"/> 
        </bean> -->




</beans>
```

**CassandraConfig.java**

```
package ai.sys.webutils;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SchemaAction;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:/spring/cxf-config.xml" })
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "ai.sys.core.doa" })
public class JPAConfig {

  //private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JPAConfig.class);

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Bean
  public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {

    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
    cluster.setContactPoints(env.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
    cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("cassandra.port")));

    return cluster;
  }

  @Bean
  public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
    return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
  }

  @Bean
  public CassandraConverter converter() {
    return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
  }

  @Bean
  public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {

    CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
    session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
    session.setKeyspaceName(env.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace"));
    session.setConverter(converter());
    session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS);

    return session;
  }

  @Bean
  public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
  }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695673/document-root-element-beans-must-match-doctype-root-null

Comment: @Boaz I figured it out. The error was I used PropertySource instead of ImportResource. Anyway Thanks :)